# How to pass a JavaScript variable to a Django variable

Tags: javascript, django, templates, variables

In my Django app I want to allow an admin to edit all the users (change groups etc.) and I am passing form data that includes the selected users username with JavaScript to another template. I want to use this username to make a query on users to find the correct information required for to change things on the user object.

**How do I pass a JavaScript variable inside a template to a Django variable?**

In first template users.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'app:edituser' %}" method="get" name="form">
    <p>
        <b>Username: </b>{{ i.username }}
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-danger" style="float:right" href="{% url 'app:all_users' %}" onClick="deleteUser()">Delete</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="value" name="username" value="{{ i.username }}" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-info" style="float:right" type="submit">Edit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

In second template edituser.html:

```
<h1>Edit user</h1>

<p><b>Username: </b><span id="data"></span></p>
<p><b>Groups: </b><span id="data1"></span></p>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'authenticator_app:all_users' %}">Cancel</a>

<script>
    // Get the wanted parameters from the previous page's form.
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }

    // Parameters
    var name = getParameterByName('username');
    var group = getParameterByName('groups');

    // Add the data to elements in html
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML = group;
</script>
```

I'm new to Django so detailed answers are appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to do all the user management by yourself instead of using the Django Admin that has this out of the box?

Comment: Yes. It's an internship assignment and this was a specific requirement.